# Stack overflow in VS multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading

When I try to create a thread like this

```
someFunc(void* param){
char currFile[500000];
char currKeyBoard[24576];   
char currImage[500000]; 
char currAddInfo[12000];
}
_beginthread( someFunc, 0,NULL );
```

The program crash whith stackoverflow exception.But when I do this

```
    someFunc(void* param){
char currFile[500000];
char currKeyBoard[24576];   
char currImage[500000]; 
}
_beginthread( someFunc, 0,NULL );
```

the program don`t crash.Why?

Comment: You might find this useful: [Thread Stack Size (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686774%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is the second function allocates less memory on the stack than the first. That is way too much stuff to allocate.

Use vectors instead, they'll allocate it on the heap, and since they manage their own memory you won't have to.